# Custom tool using react-email-editor

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a custom tool into the react component, and I only found the Unlayer documentation, which provides zero helpful documentation for this component. It assumes the user is using the CDN for Unlayer and has access to the unlayer global object, which makes all their documentation useless to me. I have the react-email-editor component set up in my project and working quite well, and I need to add a custom tool for the 'Image' tool.

My main goal was to get rid of the "Magic Image" feature inside the default "Image" tool. I tried injecting css to my react-email-editor component like `.magic_image_panel { display: none; }` but I couldn't manage to remove it.

So now I am trying to disable the default "Image" tool and make a custom one, but I can't find anywhere how to do this using react-email-editor and without having to access the `unlayer` object. Of course I checked all the unlayer documentation, tried everything I could find on the internet (there is not much btw) but I did not succeed.

Comment: More code and reference image is required to understand the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove the "Magic image" feature in react you can turn off the ai feature by passing these options to the component:

```
options={{
      features: { ai: false }
    }}
```